# Gravitational $N$-body mergers?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, computational-physics, gravitational-waves, neutron-stars

Beyond binary systems and its mergers, have numerical relativity groups computed an approximation to $N$-body GW signals/waveforms or is that a hard unsolved task?

Comment: It doesn’t seem important to do, because as far as I know mergers of more than two compact objects at a time are extremely unlikely.

Comment: To my knowledge only binary inspirals/merges and (head-on)collisions of two compact objects (see eg. https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.2797) have been simulated in numerical relativity (NR). As mentioned by @G.Smith the effort in terms of working and CPU hours to set a full NR simulation of a three-body does not seem worth it. Especially since the parameter space in terms of initial conditions for such an event looks huge to me.